# Diagram from data connection in excel

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, excel-2007, excel-2010

I've made a data-connection through MS-Query that has 3 parameters that are changable in the sheet and changes the data in the table based on changes in the parameters. So far so good, but my problem is that I want to connect a diagram to this.

In my stored procedure in MS SQL serv I've got the fields I want to use converted as money, but the excel does not understand that and has it set as general? I want excel to understand them as numbers.

[image: Here is a picture of the table with updated parameters]

I want it to understand that numbers instead of general which it does at the moment. Reason I want to make easy dynamic diagrams of it.

Best Regards

Comment: `1` What does this have to do with VBA? `2` Why not format the columns as Numbers before import the data?

Comment: Sorry about that missclick, hmm I've done that beforehand. It seems like there is something I'm doing wrong. If you doubleclick the cell it automatically transforms it to number. But as default when updated does not

Comment: I'm not an expert on Excel but I'm guessing that having MS-SQL return currency values with a comma in them may have confused Excel (Maybe excel expected a period instead of comma in the numbers) and it set the type to "general"